# Weird Line with Plank?

Tags: configuration, dock, plank

I have installed Plank and used the Azeny Theme and I got this weird line and I don’t know how to remove it. I have only changed little thing like Icon Zoom in the settings. Are there any Information I should provide?

I use Xfce and installed plank through the terminal.
It happens, no matter which theme I use, I tried it also with other themes and also the default one. The problem persists.

[The Plank is one the left.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjDaG.jpg)

Comment: Are you using GNOME? Did you install any extensions?

Comment: I edited the question. Any other Information needed?

Comment: Looks like an issue with your theme, do you have the same issue when you change to a different theme?

Comment: Yes, I have, also with the default one